# Update code over Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet

I've got an Arduino faithfully monitoring our sewer lift pump. It talks to the world over Ethernet (with PoE). I'm wondering if there is any way to load new code over the Ethernet as well. Any ideas if this could be done?

I imagine that using the boot loader might be out of the question, but perhaps it would be possible to upload a new system image – perhaps onto an SD card – and then use a modified boot loader to discover the new image and copy it into place.

Comment: You can update it in any way you can figure out how to write in the bootloader.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation (or descriptions) of how the boot loader works – short of reading the code?

Comment: It works exactly as described in Atmel's datasheets and application notes.

Comment: See http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=16812.msg122380#msg122380 or even better https://github.com/LowPowerLab/DualOptiboot.

Answer (score 1):

A bootloader to network-boot might be too large to leave enough code space for your application. Your second suggestion sounds more workable - to collect & verify the entire new image in secondary storage first, then call a storage-to-flash boot loader. You really don't want to start loading an image that then suffers damage in transit, or to have the link go down mid-download. The likely only way out of that is a site-visit. Saving first lets you confirm the integrity of the new image before you start over-writing any of the old one.